# Macro as option of tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to store some options of `tcolorbox` in a macro (because they may changes) for later use. But the following method fails.

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\theoption}{colback=red,boxrule=3pt}
\tcbset{myoption/.style={code={\theoption}}}

\begin{tcbitemize}[myoption]
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

But the option colback and boxrule have not any effect.
So, how to make a marco as option of tcolorbox

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: I don't understand why you need to use a macro here, when you have defined a style. If you need to change it at some later stage, just do `\tcbset{myoption/.style={colback=blue,boxrule=1pt}` or something.

Comment: Your document misses the class and the correct loading of `tcolorbox`

Comment: There *is* a way of doing what you want, but in many instances a solution like Christian Hupfer's or Sam Carter's below is superior.

Comment: Thanks so much for all these kindly valuable information!!

Comment: @lyl: The correct way to thank users here is to accept one of the provided answers and upvote all useful ones

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 'correct' (but most likely not the only one) way of adding options and evaluating them from macros is to 
use

```
code={\pgfkeysalsofrom{\someoption}}
```

Please don't use `\the...` names, those are basically 'reserved' for counter output names like `\thesection` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\someoption}{colback=red,boxrule=3pt}
\tcbset{myoption/.style={code={\pgfkeysalsofrom{\someoption}}}}

\begin{tcbitemize}[myoption]
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
\end{tcbitemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This is a perfect soluntion!!!

Comment: Still, why is "\tcbset{myoption/.style={code={\someoption}}}" or  "\tcbset{myoption/.style={\someoption}" a wrong way?

Comment: @lyl: `\someoption` is not expanded to give the keys you desire. You must inform `tcolorbox` first, that `\someoption` contains keys with `\pgfkeysalsofrom` -- this is a very well-known problem with many key-value interfaces

Comment: Does that mean the function of the marco \pgfkeysalsofrom is to expnad firstly its arguments, that is to say, the marco following it?

Comment: @lyl: Basically yes, it prepares the `pgfkeys` parser used in `tcolorbox` to understand the content of `\someoption`  (i.e. the keys inside there), hands over this information to the `tcolorbox`; `code={\someoption}` just prints the content of `\someoption` before anything of the box is drawn.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer to your question, but maybe a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}

\newenvironment{myitemize}[1][]{%
 \begin{tcbitemize}[colback=red,boxrule=3pt,#1]}
{\end{tcbitemize}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myitemize}
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
    \tcbitem some text
\end{myitemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all. The reason why I want to store some tcolorbox options in a marco is: the options may comes from an argument of the other marco, and this argument may vary and it is a string which need to be handled to the form of tcolorbox options. So, anyone can help me with this? Thanks a lot.